# not getting proper base_url in codeigniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

i am getting this type of url when trying to access pages other than index page

```
http://localhost:8012/health-care/8012//localhost/health-care/index.php/index.php/home
```

but url to access page must be

```
http://localhost:8012/health-care/index.php/home
```

my problem in url is: "it is duplicating url after "i h`http://localhost:8012/healthcare/` that should not be duplicated.

i have autoloaded url helper in autoload.php as well as manually in constructor of controller. my base_url in conf

`$config['base_url'] = 'http//localhost:8012/health-care/index.php/';`

Guide me about this problem.

in addition to tell you that i have two app fron one codeigniter i.e. frontend and backend.

Url for backend works properly but for frontend its giving me mistakes what to do ?

Comment: Do one thing first. in your default controller at the top of page type `echo base_url(); exit(0);` and tell me what comes out?

Comment: http//localhost:8012/health-care/index.php/

Comment: it is advisable and also a proper way to set your base_url as  `http//localhost:8012/`. Now add in your question your syntax from where you getting improper output like `http://localhost:8012/health-care/8012//localhost/health-care/index.php/index.php/home`

Comment: Please try empty url ```$config['base_url'] = '';```, it works for me...

Comment: kishor10d it gives me follwing error and url   http://[::1]/health-care/index.php/find_doctor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess file was not working. just replaced file and my problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http//localhost:8012/health-care/';
```

used this base url you getting this url

http://localhost:8012/health-care/index.php/home

Answer (score 0):

Y0u have to change  this line

```
http://localhost:8012/health-care/index.php/home
```

to this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http//localhost:8012/health-care/';
```

Please have a try.

Comment: same problem. its giving me same url

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8012/health-care/';
```

and also make `index_page` as empty like this:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```